# Zips in ajaxfileupload firefox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I can't upload zip files in the ajax control toolkit fileupload.
On every other browser it works, but in firefox zip files get blocked somehow.
When I click on a zip file to upload it, it doesn't even show up in the ajaxupload.
zips are added in the allowed filetypes.
What else could be the problem?

Comment: Execute this script in browser's console, then try to select zip file and check console log message: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/v58KD/

Comment: it says: "uncaught exception: InternalError: too much recursion", any idea what that means?

Comment: nevermind, the recursion error was because a ";" was missing on the end of  that piece of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks to the comment of Yuriy, apparently older versions of firefox don't give the extension `zip` but `x-zip-compressed`, so I just had to add `x-zip-compressed` to the allowed filetypes.